# Finding out UIDS from a large mysql dataset where the data has not changed 'n' times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows.

```
id(Primary) uid   data      Time
1           1       20      2019-05-12 10:17:26
2           2       23      2019-05-12 10:17:26
3           3       45      2019-05-12 10:17:26
4           4       16      2019-05-12 10:17:26
5           2       23      2019-05-12 10:18:26
6           1       26      2019-05-12 10:18:26
7           4       15      2019-05-12 10:18:26
8           3       41      2019-05-12 10:18:26
9           4       15      2019-05-12 10:19:26
10          2       23      2019-05-12 10:19:26
11          3       38      2019-05-12 10:19:26
12          1       31      2019-05-12 10:19:26
13          3       48      2019-05-12 10:20:26
14          4       15      2019-05-12 10:20:26
15          1       19      2019-05-12 10:20:26
16          2       23      2019-05-12 10:20:26
17          1       22      2019-05-12 10:21:26
18          4       15      2019-05-12 10:21:26
19          2       23      2019-05-12 10:21:26
20          3       43      2019-05-12 10:21:26
```

I want to find out the unique UIDs where the most recent 'n' data entries has been the same. In the above data, when n=5, I need 2 as the result. when n=4, I need 2 and 4 in the result set.

Comment: Do you have a way to sort these rows like they are showing here? Otherwise it would be difficult when you have no way to determine rows "before" or "after" other rows.

Comment: @Progman There are other columns I can use. Such as timestamp. Will that help?

Comment: @Progman updated the table with more info

Comment: Can the data repeat themself for a given `uid` after it was already "used before"? Is the following "data" sequence possible for a given `uid`: 23, 23, 23, 23, 48, 23, 23, 19, 25, 23, 23, 23?

Comment: @Progman yes it is possible, but I am looking only for the cases where the most recent 'n' datapoints are the same.  So, in your example case,I do need that uid, but if the data looks like   23, 23, 23, 23, 48, 23, 23, 19, 25, 23, 23, 26 then I dont need this uid.

Comment: @Strawberry In the sample data, uid =4 has data =15 in 4 rows. But it can be more, or less too. The key is to have a query that can be programatic with 'n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight forward approach uses `ALL` and a subquery getting the last *n* (let *n*=5 from now on) records using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    t1.uid
                    FROM elbat t1) x
       WHERE (SELECT t2.data
                     FROM elbat t2
                     WHERE t2.uid = t1.uid
                     ORDER BY time DESC
                     LIMIT 1) = ALL (SELECT t3.data
                                            FROM elbat t3
                                            WHERE t3.uid = t1.uid
                                            ORDER BY time DESC,
                                                     id DESC
                                            LIMIT 5);
```

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't allow limit in subqueries to `ALL`.
In MySQL 8 we can fix this by adding another subquery in the sub query in which we use the `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    t1.uid
                    FROM elbat t1) x
       WHERE (SELECT t2.data
                     FROM elbat t2
                     WHERE t2.uid = x.uid
                     ORDER BY time DESC
                     LIMIT 1) = ALL (SELECT x.data
                                            FROM (SELECT t3.data
                                                         FROM elbat t3
                                                         WHERE t3.uid = x.uid
                                                         ORDER BY time DESC,
                                                                  id DESC
                                                         LIMIT 5) x);
```

Again unfortunately this won't work on versions lower than 8 because values from the outer query cannot be referenced over more than one level, hence `x.uid` isn't known in the most inner subquery.

But we can check the count of the following rows, that we get in another subquery, to be less than 5 (*n*).

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    t1.uid
                    FROM elbat t1) x
       WHERE (SELECT t2.data
                     FROM elbat t2
                     WHERE t2.uid = x.uid
                     ORDER BY time DESC
                     LIMIT 1) = ALL (SELECT t3.data
                                            FROM elbat t3
                                            WHERE t3.uid = x.uid
                                                  AND (SELECT count(*)
                                                              FROM elbat t4
                                                              WHERE t4.uid = t3.uid
                                                                    AND (t4.time > t3.time
                                                                          OR t4.time = t3.time
                                                                             AND t4.id > t3.id)) < 5);
```

Note that this will also return results for `uid` where there are less than 5 (*n*) rows but all with equal `data`. If in such a case you want to exclude the respective `uid` you need to add another subquery getting the count of the last row for an `uid` and check if it's larger than or equal to 5 (*n*). Just take one of the subqueries to `ALL` and let it return `count(*)` instead of `t3.data` to get the count.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9db05dd0f54dd47d99e4a8fbf838dda9)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and update soon. It will take a moment for me to wrap my head around this :P